# How to change colors of Gui-elements belonging to preferences?

Tags: android, styles, preferences

I have a `PreferenceFragment`, which displays several kinds of `Preferences`.

Is it possible to change that blue color of the switch which belongs to a `SwitchPreference` and the radio buttons, line and title of the dialog which belongs to the `ListPreference` by assigning own colors to style-attributes ?
My base theme is `Theme.Holo` by the way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason you do not want to use AppCompat? Recent releases of AppCompat have made many new options for theming that were not available to us in Holo. (Apart from overriding drawable assets).

If you do want to stick with Holo, http://android-holo-colors.com/ is a very nice for generating those needed assets. They also have an intelliJ plugin.

Comment: Thx for the link. Is there any good reference for working with AppCompat ?

Comment: [https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) 

This is a great reference. Just recall the ActionBarActivity is now deprecated and AppCompatActivity has now taken its place.
This [https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) explains that refactor for you.